# Which direction is this pointer heading to in this LinkedList?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I do not understand the logic in `def insert_beginning(self, new_value)`. We want to make the value 5 as the `self.head_node`. Shouldn't it be `self.head_node.set_next_node(new_node)` which produces 5 -> 70 -> 5675, while `new_node.set_next_node(self.head_node)` produces 5 <- 70 <- 5675 which is in the opposite direction and have 5675 as the `self.head_node`?

```py
class Node:
  def __init__(self, value, next_node=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next_node = next_node

  def get_value(self):
    return self.value

  def get_next_node(self):
    return self.next_node

  def set_next_node(self, next_node):
    self.next_node = next_node

# Our LinkedList class
class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self, value=None):
    self.head_node = Node(value)

  def get_head_node(self):
    return self.head_node

  def insert_beginning(self, new_value):
    new_node = Node(new_value)
    new_node.set_next_node(self.head_node)
    self.head_node = new_node


# Test your code by uncommenting the statements below - did your list print to the terminal?
ll = LinkedList(5)
ll.insert_beginning(70)
ll.insert_beginning(5675)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ll = LinkedList(5)` create a linked list with one node, which also the head node, the value it contains is `5`, 
`ll.insert_beginning(70)`, first create a new node, `70`, then make the old head behind it, `70->5`, then what `self.head_node = new_node`does is to let the head of linked list to be this new node.

In short, `ll.insert_beginning(val)` keeps creating a new node and let this node be the head of the linked list.

---

Explanations on `new_node.set_next_node(self.head_node)` in `ll.insert_beginning(70)`:

```
What ll = linkedlist(5) does:
  address(x201)
-----------------
|   5  | Null   |    -----> It's a node
-----------------

What ll.insert_beginning(70) does:

   x304
-----------------
|  70  | Null   |     ----> It's another node 
-----------------
     x304                         x201
-----------------           ----------------
|  70  | x201   |     ----> |  5    |  Null |
-----------------           -----------------
```

Comment: hello, isn't the `self.head_node` supposed to be the first to point TOWARDS other nodes instead of being the last to be pointed back?

Comment: @SharonNg `self.head_node` is the head node, followed by other nodes.

Comment: so shouldn't it be 5 -> 70 instead of 5 <- 70?

Comment: @SharonNg Right.